# How to use previous version of dataset as input in palantir foundry code repository

Tags: palantir-foundry

How to use previous version of dataset as input in palantir foundry code repository.
I want to take input of pervious version of dataset and apply the transformation on it in code repository. I know it is possible in contour but I need to write code in pyspark.

how to use previous version of dataset as input in palantir foundry code repository

Comment: Not possible. You can use API calls to create a branch from a previous transaction and use that as input using the 'branch' argument in 'Input'. Selecting a specific transaction_rid is not possible in the transforms API.

Comment: Do you want to take the previous version of your transform output or is it for one of transform inputs?

Comment: one way is to download the previous version of the dataset and upload into foundry again and use it in the code repository. I had similar requirement as the latest version of the data was corrupted and wanted to use older version.

Comment: It is the input used in transform script for which I need older version. My requirement is to write a script where I need to compare the current version and current -1  version of input dataset every day

Comment: Maybe you should look into incremental builds? You could have a dataset that always contains the last two days of data - and then build something off that? Check these docs and maybe that will give you some ideas that will fit your use case: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/incremental-overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use
df= output_dataset.dataframe('current').localCheckpoint()